# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Operators' Azure DevOps Angular 8

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, rxjs

[image]

Please have a look at this image.

I'm trying to setup Azure DevOps for .Net core project with Angular, but while in the publish step it throws an error "error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Operators'" even though it works locally with successful publish, once the pipeline job runs it gives this error. Using the latest version of rxjs with Angular 8.

Comment: `'rxjs/operators'` != `rxjs/Operators'`. It's case sensitive.

Comment: Yes figured that out, I am using windows for development, and building my app which does not care for the cases, while I was using the Linux in Azure DevOps to build and publish the code that was throwing error. When I used windows for publishing there was no more error, it was the case issue.

Answer (score 2):

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Operators' Azure DevOps Angular 8

This is a common error, we can find the solution in a simple web by searching the key words "`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Operators`".

The **solution** for this error is that the **O** in `Operators` in the import statement should be **in small case** `operators`.

Generally, by default, Mac/windows file system are case insensitive.

Hence, the following line in a Typescsript file,

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/Operators/switchMap';
```

would not throw any error if you build the Angular project with command `ng build --prod` on Mac/windows OS.

But if you run the same project on Linux, it is likely to throw that error.

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755950/angular-7-ci-rxjs-operators-cannot-find-module) for some more details.